# How to save verbose output

Tags: r, output, verbose

I would like to save the the verbose output of whatever R function to either a variable or file.

In other words, the verbose console output of `whatever_R_function(abc, verbose=TRUE)` should be saved somewhere.

I tried to play with `verbose.output <- capture.output(whatever_R_function(abc, verbose = TRUE))` but it doesn't work as `capture.output()` captures the non-verbose part of the output only.

Two examples:

`install.packages('devtools', verbose=TRUE)`

or

```
library(emayili)
smtp <- server(host = '...',
               port = ...,
               username = '...',
               password = '...')
email <- envelope() %>%
    from('...') %>%
    to('...') %>%
    bcc('...') %>%
    reply('...') %>%
    subject('...') %>%
    html('...') %>%
    attachment('...')
smtp(email, verbose = TRUE)
```

Thank you.

R 4.0.2 - RStudio 1.3.1093 - macOS 10.15.7

Comment: It would be great if you could give an example of a specific R function. The answer will depend on how the verbose output is displayed - whether it's `print`, `cat`, `message`, or something else...

Comment: Examples added in the original question. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't dig in to the `install.packages` code, but [`smtp` appears to use `cat` directed to `stderr()`](https://github.com/datawookie/emayili/blob/4f0d5750ebc4ba229037e5c0529d5f1f7d4aa9e6/R/server.R#L46) when `verbose = TRUE`.

The `?capture.output` help page says:

> Messages sent to `stderr()` (including those from `message`, `warning` and `stop`) are captured by `type = "message"`. Note that this can be “unsafe” and should only be used with care.

So, I believe if you use `capture.output(..., type = "message")`, you should get it. There's a strong possibility that this will work for `install.packages` too.

I'm not sure why this is considered unsafe or what care you should take with it...