# R: Accessing the Results of R Code that was Aborted

Tags: r, function, optimization, abort

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I have the following function:

```
library(GA)

Rastrigin <- function(x1, x2)
{
  20 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x1) + cos(2*pi*x2))
}
```

As an example, suppose I try to optimize this function using some optimization algorithm and request for a very large number of iterations:

```
GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness =  function(x) -Rastrigin(x[1], x[2]),
         lower = c(-5.12, -5.12), upper = c(5.12, 5.12), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 10000, run = 10000)
```

After running this code, I quickly clicked the "Red Stop Sign Button" to abort this code:

[image]

As seen here:

- I requested the optimization algorithm to run for 10000 iterations, but I manually aborted the code after 959 iterations.
- As a result, the "GA object" (i.e. the R object that stores the progress of the optimization) was never created.

  > GA

  Error: object 'GA' not found

[image]

**My Question:** The computer has still performed a significant amount of work - **ideally, I would like to see how far the computer reached with the optimization and inspect the most current solution obtained before the code was aborted.** But since the "GA object" was never created, I can not extrapolate what the most current solution was from the log - I can only see the "mean" and "best" value of the function evaluated at the most current solution (and the not the current solution itself).

For example, suppose I let the optimization run to completion - I can then access the entire results of the optimization:

```
GA_complete <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness =  function(x) -Rastrigin(x[1], x[2]),
         lower = c(-5.12, -5.12), upper = c(5.12, 5.12), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 10, run = 10)

head(GA_complete@population)
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.04222106 -0.04219359
[2,]  0.33339796 -0.03329398
[3,]  0.59785640 -0.31436130
[4,] -0.07623396  0.15844942
[5,]  0.96052009 -0.04702174
[6,]  0.02373485 -0.03466375

head(GA_complete@fitness)
[1]  -0.7027423 -15.3337890 -32.5594724  -5.7160470  -1.6641805  -0.3490039
```

**Is it possible to somehow "access" the most current solution when the code is aborted?** **Can we somehow access the log and view the intermediate results/progress of aborted code?**

Thanks!

Comment: I'm really interested in seeing what you get from this question. It's a great question. I'm going to guess that it will rely heavily on what function you want something akin to verbosity for. See if any of these offer something that might work: [`capture.output`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797849/how-to-save-verbose-output) or [`rlog`](https://blog.sellorm.com/2021/06/16/getting-started-with-logging-in-r/).

Comment: Thank you so much @Kat! I am also really interested! I will check these functions out!

Comment: This is also related to another a question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71719381/r-correctly-specifying-constraints-in-a-function .. trying to figure it at all out this weekend!

Comment: I suspect that there is no way to do this "in general", as there is only a log if the function actually writes to a log. What you _can_ do is write a wrapper around the optimizer that _does_ write to a log every `n` iterations, by calling the optimizer `m` times each with `maxiter = n`. Call `i+1` would use the estimate generated in call `i` as a starting point...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to save work in the middle of large-scale processing relies wholly on the function itself, which means that if you want to have an interruptible call and preserve the interim results, then you need to rewrite the function itself so that it has this, will catch errors gracefully, and return data. One thing that would advise this is https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-catch-the-keyboard-interruption-in-r/7336, where one can use `tryCatch` with the `interrupt=` handler, as in:

```r
tryCatch(for (i in 1:1e6) mean(rcauchy(1:1e6)), interrupt = function(e) "foo")
```

I think the conventional use of `tryCatch` is to catch `error=` and possibly `warning=`, but the use of `interrupt=` is not as often seen in the wild. (I've not looked for it ... but I've never had a function react gracefully to me interrupting it. I do know that some `purrr::` functions use it.)

If you're not willing to invest the time to rewrite `ga`'s internals in order to handle this (perhaps not a trivial undertaking), I suggest you handle it externally. Instead of running it `10000` times, perhaps you only run it `100` or `10` or so, and externally repeat it to fill to the desired volume.

Here's a helper function that might work for you. (I've not tested it with `ga`, but I imagine it can still be adapted to work with that.)

```r
interruptible <- function(expr, n = 1) {
  stopifnot(n > 0)
  n <- as.integer(n)
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  out <- list()
  interrupted <- structure(list(), class = "interrupted")
  i <- 0L
  while (i < n) {
    this <- tryCatch(eval(expr), interrupt = function(e) interrupted)
    if (inherits(this, "interrupted")) break
    out <- c(out, list(this))
    i <- i + 1L
  }
  if (i < n) warning(sprintf("interrupted, %i/%i completed", i, n), call. = FALSE)
  out
}
```

And a simple test-run:

```r
out <- interruptible({Sys.sleep(2); message(Sys.time()); runif(1);}, 3)
# 2022-04-02 13:55:46
# 2022-04-02 13:55:48
# 2022-04-02 13:55:50
out
# [[1]]
# [1] 0.2934904
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.7578942
# [[3]]
# [1] 0.8208736
```

Let's interrupt that mid-run:

```r
out <- interruptible({Sys.sleep(2); message(Sys.time()); runif(1);}, 3)
# 2022-04-02 13:55:55
# 2022-04-02 13:55:57
C-c C-c                           # <--- I use emacs/ess, this is me interrupting it
# Warning: interrupted, 1/3 completed
out
# [[1]]
# [1] 0.7229554
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.4721477
```

It is up to the caller to determine how to combine the results. In this case, it might simply be to `c`oncatenate the results (`unlist` or `do.call(c, out)`), but if a frame or matrix is returned, then it might be combined using `do.call(rbind, out)` or `dplyr::bind_rows(out)` or `data.table::rbindlist(out)`.

I suspect (without testing) that you might be able to do something like:

```r
GA_complete <- interruptible(
  ga(type = "real-valued", 
     fitness =  function(x) -Rastrigin(x[1], x[2]),
     lower = c(-5.12, -5.12), upper = c(5.12, 5.12), 
     popSize = 50, maxiter = 10, run = 10),
  n = 1000)
```

and then find a way to combine each of the results; since the return value is not a simple frame, it might be a little more elbow-grease to combine each of the `@`-slots, or perhaps you should not try to combine all of them, just the specific results you need.

N.B.: I recognize that running one genetic algorithm for 10 generations and repeating 1000 times is not the same as one single 10000-generation run. Unfortunately, in order to get that effect while being able to interrupt it with a saved-state, you will need to alter `ga` itself, and that I'm not willing to just "attempt" for an SO question. It is further complicated by the fact that `ga` can run in [parallel](https://github.com/luca-scr/GA/blob/master/man/ga.Rd#L104-L105).

Comment: Thank you! I interrupted the code and got the following output

Comment: > interruptible({Sys.sleep(2); message(Sys.time()); runif(1);}, 3)
2022-04-02 14:21:11
2022-04-02 14:21:13
2022-04-02 14:21:15
[[1]]
[1] 0.7912601

[[2]]
[1] 0.289589

[[3]]
[1] 0.5904759

Comment: is this the final answer obtained before interruption? thanks!

Comment: The result after interrupting the call to `interruptible` is all of the outputs returned from the first `i-1` calls to the `expr`ession. The current call to the `expr`ession that was interrupted has no output (because it was interrupted).